# Getting data only when logged in

Tags: ios, swift

In my app i have some functions: login, getNews, getWeather. The last two functions can be executed only if the user is logged in. I don't want to login everytime also if the user is already logged in, so if the two lasts functions returns a not logged in error i want to login and then executed the queue of functions that required the login.
That's only an example, the real code is much longer and the functions that depends on login are more than two. I want to know the best solution to manage that situation.

Comment: You can use dispatch_group for a sequence of web service calls .

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can store in `UserDefaults` state of logged in user or not. And base on this call any functions you want.

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear. I know that but i store cookies.. and sometime i can get logged out.

Answer (score 0):

When the user has logged in you can store his credential in the keychain.
Look here for a brief tutorial:

[Tutorial One](http://hayageek.com/ios-keychain-tutorial/)

[Tutorial Two](https://www.raywenderlich.com/92667/securing-ios-data-keychain-touch-id-1password).

Then you can check every time if you have his credentials stored and log in automatically, and then perform the functions getNews and getWeather.

Comment: My question is about GDC, i don't want to login everytime. I want to login one time, then store sessionid cookie and while i won't be logged out because the session expires i want to continue using that to avoid useless request.

Comment: @Zac, does the user log in to some external server?

Comment: Yes, infact it is out of my control

Comment: @Zac, so you have nothing to do, but log in again every time you're logged out by the server. If you save the cookie locally and it expires there is nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

To store data between your app launches, you can try any of the following two methods :

1) The very simple solution would be to store the user data in your UserDefaults in the form of user dictionary. 
for ex. `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userDict, forKey: @"User Dictionary")`. This can be painful if your userDict is large or difficult to make.

2) The other solution can be, use a archiver to store the user data. You can make your custom archiver from this [link](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/).

Answer (score 0):

So when user success login use `NSUserDefaults` logged `value` = `1`

Example;

Add `prefs` with that codes.

```
let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
```

Success login after `set` logged `object` inside `1`.

```
  let logged = 1
  prefs.setObject(logged, forKey: "logged")
```

And check user if `logged` or `not logged` show login

> You can add under below check logged codes everywhere inside project

```
  if prefs.valueForKey("logged") as! Int == 1 {

    }else{

        // go login
    }
```

For `logout` you can `use` ;

```
  let logged = 0
  prefs.setObject(logged, forKey: "logged")
```

Thanks